# vscode can't find buildifier on remote instance

Tags: visual-studio-code, bazel

I'm bumping into a weird vscode issue. I use vscode to ssh into my EC2 instance. I primarily use bazel as the dependency management and build system for development. I installed buildifier, and included in my path variable however vscode still doesn't detect it. If I type `buildifier <some bazel build file>` in the terminal in vscode, it works perfectly, but if I try to use the formatting shortcut on the file using vscode, it doesn't. I went to the extension settings, and in the remote settings I explicitly put `buildifier` as the executable command. Still not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's likely that the path you've set is set somewhere that the vscode remote server isn't looking. So it might be in your shell path but not the vscode remote servers path when it starts up.

As a workaround find the full path of buildifier e.g.

```
whereis buildifier
```

Then simply copy past the full path of buildifier into your settings under the `Bazel: Buildifier Executable` section.